# Springboot Qaurtz Scheduler skips the next fire time

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using Quartz Scheduler to schedule some Jobs, when I was using a simple trigger for hourly and daily intervals it was working fine.

For Monthly and Yearly schedules I moved to Cron Scheduler, it always skips the next fire time
If I schedule for Feb 10, but it starts from Mar 10
if I use to run every 2 months it starts on April 10

I tried

```
0 0 0 10 JAN-DEC/2 ?
```

Also with

```
0 0 0 10 */2 ?
```

Code I use to create the Job trigger

```
  trigger.withSchedule(cronSchedule(cornExpression)
      .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
      .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()).startAt(schedulerOptions.getStartsAt());
```

Value of schedulerOptions.getStartsAt()

```
Thu Feb 10 20:00:00 IST 2022
```

the trigger is **TriggerBuilder**

Here are the Debugger Values of the Trigger Object

[image]

After creating the Trigger, I checked for the next fire time, it skipped the next month, below is the debug value of the nextfiretime

[image]